# Why cant Hinduism accept Guna Based Flexible Varna system as Buddhism?

Tags: buddhism

Buddha says "While the differences between these species are defined by their birth,the differences between humans are not defined by their birth.In individual human bodies you can’t find such distinctions. The distinctions among humans are spoken of by convention.For name and clan are assigned as mere convention in the world.Arising by mutual agreement,they’re assigned to each individual.For a long time this misconception has prejudiced those who don’t understand.Ignorant, they declare that one is a brahmin by birth.You’re not a brahmin by birth,nor by birth a non-brahmin.You’re a brahmin by your deeds,
and by deeds a non-brahmin.(https://suttacentral.net/mn98/en/sujato)

Comment: Not to offend, But Varna System belongs to Vedas and not to Buddhism. Since by birth Buddha was a Sanatani; (however later he did veda-ninda and chose the path of Buddhism), it is possible that he still kept some teachings of Vedas and spread it.

Comment: Varna system is flexible. But later due to some corrupt brahmins changes it to gain power and authority.

Comment: @Kumar - varna system is NOT flexible. Due to some corrupt shudras they changed it to divide people and gain votes.

Comment: Yes, one does not become a brahmin by birth. Even Yudhishtira says so. If you listen to upanyasa of elders, they say that this is a Tarka (logic) statement to be understood with Negation. Can Water be made with Hydrogen ? No. Can Water be made with Oxygen ? No. Can Water be made with Hydrogen AND Oxygen ? Yes. Similarly, Can one be brahmin by Birth ? No. Can one be brahmin by Deeds ? No. Can one be brahmin by Birth AND Deeds ? Yes. People seem to forget the fact that your varna in current birth is determined by your deeds in previous birth.

Comment: So this 'rigid' varna system you're complaining about is actually flexible (because you can change varnas over different lives), and 'nepotism' you're complaining about is actually a meritocracy, but this system gives importance to deeds done not only in this birth but in previous ones as well. If a system gave importance only to deeds done in current birth, that would be like giving a murderer in a prison Padma Bhushan because he saved a dog. One good act in this life is not enough to counter many bad acts in previous lives.

Comment: @ram dude, I am a Brahmin by birth too. But I believe you have to understand the Brahm to be a Brahmin. There were some corrupt Brahmins in past you cannot deny that and It is also true that there are some corrupt Shudras nowadays doing the same to gain power and authority.

Comment: @Kumar - if you truly understand brahm, you won't be on this planet anymore. so understanding brahm is the 'goal' for brahmins, not the criteria to be a brahmin.

Comment: @ram no, you can understand it in this life. Read Atma Bodha text by Adi Sankaracharya. It has information to understand your true self (Atma). Atma which is God part itself.

Comment: @Kumar - Those who say they understand do not understand. Those who say they do not understand, understand.

Comment: @ram LOL, its about nature. I never said I understand. But I am willing to know it. Second, Adi Sankaracharya is a great holy person. So as many of our ancient sages they are holy and have attained the enlightenment. They understand the Brahm and themself. So, we can do that too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why cant Hinduism accept Guna Based Flexible Varna system as Buddhism?

Because it goes against Vedas and is impossible to implement. Plus a true Brahmana, Kshatriya, etc. is one by birth and by action.

> **Chhandogya Upanishad 5.10.7** - Those whose conduct has been good here
> will shortly get birth such as a Brahmana, a
> kshatriya, or a vaishya. But those whose conduct has been evil will be
> born in evil births shortly such as the birth of a dog,
> or as a pig, or a chandala.

> **Maitrayani Samhita 1.4.1** - We know not if we are brahmins or non-Brahmins. ...Therefore, when recounting our gotra-pravaras, say that the devas are our ancestors.

> **Taittiriya Brahmana** - 'When a Sudra woman is the mistress of an Arya, she does not seek wealth for prosperity.' Therefore they (the priests) do not bestow royal consecration on the son of a Vaishya woman.